# How to cope with pluralization in translations

Tags: laravel, internationalization, laravel-6.2

I have multilingual application using laravel 6.2, and i want to translate terms imported from the database, so I use the following code:

```
<td>{{ __($specs) }}</td>
```

Examples of some specs in json file:

```
"Display" : "Monitor",
"Processor" : "Procesador",
"RAM" : "RAM",
"Rear Camera" : "Cámara trasera",
```

Until now, everything is fine.

But the problem is when importing variable expressions, for example:

```
5 inches
5.5 inches ...
143 grams
165 grams ...
```

I don't want to do this every time

```
  "5 inches" : "5 pulgadas",
  "6.5 inches" : "6.5 pulgadas",
  "5.61 inches" : "5.61 pulgadas",
  "6.54 inches" : "6.54 pulgadas",
  "7 inches" : "7 pulgadas",
  .
  .
  .
```

Is there a way to translate the word "inches" and "grams" only ?

Comment: The rules for how to pluralize terms vary between languages. An infamous illustration is how Slavic languages require different cases depending on whether the number is larger than 5, lower than 20, etc.

Comment: Does this not solve your problem?
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/localization#pluralization

Comment: Thanks for the answer
Is there a suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: @AneesSaban 
No
Because I have a dynamic value in my situation